# Android Transparent edged Image Slider

Tags: android, image, android-layout, slider, android-viewflipper

I have been trying to re-create an image slider as shown in the image. Looked for a lot of image slider / Flipper libraries. But in the end, I can see that Each and every slider has some kind of gray overlay effect at the bottom of the slider. How Do I Remove that Effect which is at Description Layout of the slider?
Are there any other better libraries that provide the same functionality as the sample slider?

Main Activity::

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = MainActivity.this;

    ToolbarInit();
    BottombarInit();
    ModelItems();
    ListHandler();

    sliderLayout = findViewById(R.id.imageSlider);
    sliderLayout.setIndicatorAnimation(SliderLayout.Animations.SCALE); 
    sliderLayout.setScrollTimeInSec(8); //set scroll delay in seconds :
     setSliderViews();
}

private void setSliderViews() {

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {

        SliderView sliderView = new SliderView(this);

        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                sliderView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.slider1);
                break;
            case 1:
                sliderView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.slider2);
                break;
            case 2:
                sliderView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.slider3);
                break;
            case 3:
                sliderView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.slider4);
                break;
            case 4:
                sliderView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.slider5);
                break;
        }

        sliderView.setImageScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        sliderView.setDescription("");
        //sliderView.setDescription("setDescription " + (i + 1));
        final int finalI = i;
        sliderView.setOnSliderClickListener(new 
        SliderView.OnSliderClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSliderClick(SliderView sliderView) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is slider " + (finalI + 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //at last add this view in your layout :
        sliderLayout.addSliderView(sliderView);
    }
}
```

> XML ::

```
 <com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderLayout
            android:id="@+id/imageSlider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TranslucentStatusBar"
            app:indicator_visibility="visible"/>
```

> Sample Image Slider

[image]